# Increase number when inView with useEffect and useState

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need to show a number, that starts at 0 and increases to X. This "counting" needs to happen when user's reach the number in view, like [this example](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/javascript-animation-counter/illustration.gif).

For this, I'm trying to use useEffect, useState and useInView, from react-intersection-observer.

But, in my code, my number is a bit crazy, changing from 1 to 2 only.

I've created a component that I can use many times, this way:

```js
function NumericIndicator(props) {
  const [counting, setCounting] = useState(false);
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const [ref, inView] = useInView();

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (number < props.value) {
        setNumber(number + 1);
      } else {
        setNumber(props.value);
      }
    }, 500);
  }, [counting]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inView && !counting) {
      setCounting(true);
    }
  }, [inView]);

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <h1>{number}</h1>
      <p>
        <small>This needs to increase from 0 to {props.value}</small>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a full [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1hktyk) with my code

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin
          convallis sagittis finibus. Maecenas mauris odio, feugiat vel orci
          non, consectetur placerat turpis. Proin tincidunt ut tellus posuere
          euismod. Donec id venenatis dui. Quisque ultrices dignissim ipsum ut
          tempus. Praesent mollis elit ac magna laoreet tempus at a dui.
          Suspendisse sed venenatis arcu, quis commodo sapien. Ut at malesuada
          dui. Curabitur feugiat elementum ligula, a pellentesque tortor. Fusce
          id nisl ornare, congue dui vitae, ornare ex. Class aptent taciti
          sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
          himenaeos.
        </p>
        <p>
          Vivamus blandit leo ac magna efficitur vulputate. Praesent vitae magna
          elit. Nullam non metus nec mauris maximus tincidunt a ac velit. Aenean
          elit metus, aliquet at gravida ornare, commodo gravida nisl. Cras
          vestibulum lacinia erat sit amet cursus. Donec pretium enim porttitor
          magna tincidunt, a venenatis sem bibendum. Aenean ornare enim et odio
          pharetra iaculis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div style={{ height: '50vh', backgroundColor: '#27ae60' }}>
        <NumericIndicator value={10} />
      </div>
      <div style={{ height: '50vh', backgroundColor: '#e67e22' }}>
        <NumericIndicator value={70} />
      </div>
      <div style={{ height: '50vh', backgroundColor: '#9b59b6' }}>
        <NumericIndicator value={90} />
      </div>
      <div style={{ height: '50vh', backgroundColor: '#2c3e50' }}>
        <NumericIndicator value={110} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function NumericIndicator(props) {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const [ref, inView] = useInView();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!inView) return () => {};

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setNumber((prev) => Math.min(prev + 1, props.value));
    }, 500);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [inView, props.value, number]);

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <h1>{number}</h1>
      <p>
        <small>This needs to increase from 0 to {props.value}</small>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: a side note to improvement, in this way,  `setNumber` function will not be stopping until change the page (invoke cleanup function)

Comment: `const interval = setInterval(() => { if(number < props.value) { setNumber(prev => prev+ 1 } else { clearInterval(interval) }}, 500);`